# Angular2 app.module

Tags: angular

If we import FormsModule in app.module then we also need to import it in other sub-module to use it in sub-module?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SignupComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [RestaurantsService, LoginAuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to.

However, if you find yourself re-importing the same modules in different submodules, you can instead import commonly used modules into a CommonModule, which will export these modules

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [FormsModule],
  exports: [FormsModule]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Then, in your other subodules, simply import your CommonModule and you won't need to import FormsModule anymore.

https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-should-i-export